# Which jQuery/css menu library for working with ASP.NET TreeView or Menu controls

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm looking for a good jQuery or CSS, or combo, library to enance my left side menu in an an intranet application.  I don't like the 'hover only' expand/collapse style of the ASP.NET Menu control on its own, and I don't like the 'icon-click only' expand/collapse style of the TreeView control on its own.

I plan on trying the CSS Control Adapters, to render the menu with some self-respect, i.e. as nested `<ul>` or `<ol>` elements instead of the usual orgy of tables.  Beyond that, I need something to give a bit of style and menulike behaviour to these nested lists, and I would prefer a jQuery plugin for this.  Which should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this I'd look at [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#download).  Luckily, there's already [full articles out there](http://www.conceptdevelopment.net/Fun/Superfish/) about how to rig this up with ASP.Net :)

If you don't like the styles though/behaviors available, it's really not that complicated to write the jQuery yourself to get **exactly** what you're after, if you had an illustration of the exact look/behavior you wanted I could point you in the right direction there, usually there's not much jQuery code to do this either.

Comment: By way of an example, and almost a solution, I've found this plugin: http://www.inventpartners.com/content/jquery-concertina-menu-plugin - Only thing I need to change, is 'click on li' to expand, not 'click on text or button'.

Comment: @ProfK - Do you always have 2 levels or are there more?

Comment: @ProfK - You could do something as simple as this: http://jsfiddle.net/W2MXw/ just depends what **exact** behavior you want, pretty easy to tweak and style, let me know if you need more direction on the jQuery portion (just showing it doesn't have to be complicated).  For example: you could hide siblings so only one shows at a time, etc...whatever fits your app best.

Comment: that looks great - +1 for the jsFiddle which is new to me.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [10 best jQuery menus](http://www.ajaxline.com/10-best-jquery-menu-plugins) and [CSS Menu Control Example](http://www.asp.net/CSSAdapters/Menu.aspx).